# input cannot focus when switching webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created a simple demo, modified with webview official instance, please help to look at this problem：
https://github.com/roguexiaohuihui/input-focus

**the demo content**：

1、Run the `Cat Coding: Start cat coding session` to create the webview.

the first time you create a webview, the focus is normal

2、Run again `Cat Coding: Start cat coding session` to create the webview.

the focus is normal

3、Switching to the webview in step 1, this focus is not working

I listened for the toggle event and sent a message to the web to make it focus, but the focus didn't work

```
    this._panel.onDidChangeViewState(
        e => {
            if (this._panel.visible) {
                this._panel.webview.postMessage({ command: 'showFocus' });
                this._update();
            }
        },
        null,
        this._disposables
    );
```

media/main.js:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input_1')
input.focus()
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
    const message = event.data
    switch (message.command) {
        case 'showFocus':
            console.log('showFocus')
            console.log('input:', input)
            input.focus()  //It doesn't work here
            break
    }
})
```

vscode community problem address:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84216

the problem：
when switching webview, the plug-in transmits a signal to webview through message and actively asks the input of webview to focus again. Instead of the input being focused after the mouse click on the screen